# NO browser connectivity YES remote connectivity

Tags: active-directory

Running Windows Server 2003 R2, using terminal services to log on from local XP machines . There is no problem when i added the machine to the domain when the DNS was set to the proper value, and remote connections are up, but the workstation is unable to get on the internet via browser locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total noob-fix...I'm disappointed actually because all it took was un-checking "Automatically detect settings" in IE options.